# How to set/format the date of p:calendar on client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

First of all the current situation. I have a JSF page where a date is rendered like this

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean[date]}" >
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{Const.CALENDAR_PATTERN}"/> 
        // contains a calendar pattern, here dd.MMM yyyy
</h:outputText>
```

On another location there is a `p:calendar` input component, and I like to set the value of this calendar via a button click on the client side!

A first hard coded attempt works fine:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('calendar_id_input')
    .setAttribute('value', '21.Jan 2015');"
```

But when I am using the date, that comes from the bean, then the pattern does not match, of course:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('calendar_id_input')
    .setAttribute('value', '#{bean[date]}');"
```

This got rendered to (and would work fine as well, if the calendar would accept this pattern):

```
onclick="document.getElementById('calendar_id_input')
    .setAttribute('value', 'Sat Jan 03 18:00:57 CET 2015');"
```

So I tried using the jQuery-datepicker formatter to format the the date before I set the value in the calendar like this:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('calendar_id_input')
    .setAttribute('value', $.datepicker
          .formatDate('#{Const.CALENDAR_PATTERN}', new Date( #{bean[date]} )  ) 
     );"
```

The full rendered outcome in the last attempt looks like this, but does not work, ie the value of the calendar is not set at all:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('calendar_id_input')
   .setAttribute('value', $.datepicker
       .formatDate('dd.MMM yyyy', new Date( Sat Jan 03 18:00:57 CET 2015 )  ) 
    );
 return false;;"
```

What is wrong here and how may I fix it? Unfortunately I am not very familar with javascript and/or jQuery..

Thanks in advance!

---

According to BalusC's answer, I changed my code to:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('calendar_id_input')
.setAttribute('value', $.datepicker
.formatDate('#{Const.CALENDAR_PATTERN}', new Date(#{bean[date].time})));"
```

Now the value of the calendar is set, but no matter which pattern I try, the result is strange. E.g with the pattern `dd.MMM yyy` which I like to use, I have the strange outcome `03. JanuaryJan 2015`
I cannot imagine that there might be compatibilty conflicts with those pattern, as primefaces is build on jQuery, isn't it?

---

Additional problem:
Once the value of the calendar is set (e.g. by manually selecting a date from the datepicker), the value-attribute of the input component is updated correctly, but the calendar still shows the old value.

Comment: just think a noun and there will be plugin for jquery....

Comment: @vishalsharma I already found the formatDate-function in jQuery, but I dont get it working, as described in the last part.. Or are you talking about sth else?

Comment: there seems to be problem with jsf , *'#{bean[date]}'* , I dont know how to format values in JSF , but you can look it up on documentation ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question finally I'd like to share my solution with you. Maybe it is helpful for someone else in the future:

The PrimeFaces component `p:calendar` provides a `setDate` function in the client side API. So the final solution that I am using now reads like this

```
<p:calendar widgetVar="calendar_widget_name" />

<p:commandButton type="button"
    onclick="PF('calendar_widget_name').setDate(new Date(#{bean[date].time}));"
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

The following snippet should solve your problem:

`PF('widgetVariable').setDate(new Date(#{bean.getYourDate().time}));`